# can I use the same EntityManager (same PersistenceContext) to persist a few EntityBean of different types

Tags: java, jpa, ejb-3.0

can I use the same EntityManager (same PersistenceContext) to persist a few EntityBean of different types? for example:

```
@Stateful
public class BankServiceBean implements BankService {
@PersistenceContext(unitName="BankService")
private EntityManager em;
private Customer cust;
private Account acc = new Account();

public void addCustomer(int custId, String firstName,String lastName) { 
cust = new Customer(); 
cust.setld(custld); 
cust.setFirstName(firstName); 
cust.setLastName(lastName); 
em.persist(cust);
em.persist(acc);

}
```

Comment: Yes, you can - had you any problems with that, or why do you ask?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, only if your different Entity beans are using same `dataSource` property.

Since your EntityManager has 'transaction manager' property, which in turn has datasource property.

Comment: how do you see that my EntityManager has 'transaction manager' property ? and how do you relate entity bean to dataSource ? the EntityManager persistance context has one persistance unit that for sure